# I am unable to get desired output while assigning an *

Tags: shell

I am unable to get desired output while assigning an * to a variable and then concatining it with a string in shell..
chr function converts int to char
42 = *

```
d="$(chr 42)"
m=""
c[1]=$d
m=$m${c[1]}
echo $m
```

Comment: `echo *` is different than `echo '*'` in the same way that  `echo $m` is different than `echo "$m"`

Comment: @Avis TnM - The above code is not runnable without the definition of `chr`.

Comment: @Armali, it's probably `chr() { printf "\x$(printf '%x' "$1")"; }` -- prints the ASCII character with the given decimal number

Comment: @Avis, you have not told us what is the desired output and what is the actual output: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Before you `echo` do this: `declare -p d c m` and see if the variables contain what you expect.

Comment: Here's the other way: `ord() { printf "%d" "'$1"; }` so `ord '*'` outputs "42" -- note the single quote before "$1", which is the magic

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is working just fine, but

```
echo $m
```

exposes the argument to glob expansion.  You need to use quotes:

```
echo "$m"
```

Comment: Its not working i am doing echo "$m">>lop